# How to call an iframe in JS so that the original url is maintained in the address bar

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way in JAVASCRIPT (possibly using iframes), to keep the url of an original site when a new page appears.  Example: original site url shows [www.initialPage.com](http://www.initialPage.com).  When the user clicks ALT-Z, the new website should show the content of [www.secondaryPage.com](http://www.secondaryPage.com).  The code I thought would work looks like below.  However, when ALT-Z is selected, [www.initialPage.com](http://www.initialPage.com) stays in the url (which is what I want) but only a blank page shows.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'KeyZ':
        function prepareFrame() {
          var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
          ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.secondaryPage.com");
          ifrm.style.height = "100vh"
          ifrm.style.width = "100vw"
          document.body.replaceWith(ifrm);
        }
        prepareFrame();
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Is there something I forgot in the function to allow [www.secondaryPage.com](http://www.secondaryPage.com) to display?  I know there are security risks but this is for a very small trusted private network

Comment: Make sure www.secondaryPage.com allows to be loaded as an iframe from a different origin. `X-Frame-Options` header should not be set to `sameorigin`. If this is the case you should be able to see an error in the browser console. Also make sure the key combination you are using is not some sort of system wide key shortcut that does not get propagated to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot more experimentation on this and it seems the reason the site with the iframe ([www.secondaryPage.com](http://www.secondaryPage.com)) does not display has something to do with the initial page ([www.initialPage.com](http://www.initialPage.com)) is a secure site. When I use an un-secure site as the initial page, the secondaryPage is displayed just fine.  If anyone can provide some insight as to what I can do to have the above code work while on a secure site, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed as a FAQ-style database of easy to understand "question->answer" pairs. You are asking another question in an answer but nobody will look for your new question asked in an answer. Experts who are willing to help usually filter out answered questions so your question drops out of theirs search because it is already answered. [Use this button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) when you want to ask a new question. But in your particular case you can update your original question post with extra details and remove this post to keep your question open